# jquery function within loop not iterating

Tags: jquery, iteration

I have a problem with my code, the `title` attribute only shows `16` rather than showing all values from `1` through `15`. Why is this so can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong???

**My Code**

```
 x=1;
 while(x <= 15)
 {
     $("td#id"+x).mouseover(function(x){
     $(this).attr('title', x)           
   });
   x++;
}
```

Comment: this is part of bigger script, the coulmns of table are dynamically generated and has id's assigned, the title attribute will have the value of x , which is the iterator, so if  e.g

     <td id=1  title="1">someval</td>
     <td id=2  title="2">someval</td>
      ....
     <td id=15 title="15">someval</td>

Answer (score 9):

This is the **very common** "using a loop variable in a callback" problem.

As you're using jQuery the simplest fix is a `data` parameter to the handler:

```
 var x=1;
 while (x <= 15) {
     $("td#id"+x).mouseover({ x: x }, function(ev) {
         this.title = ev.data.x;        
     });
     x++;
 }
```

That said, why are you only setting this in a `mouseover` function?  The title should be added to the elements directly, just once:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 15; ++x) {
    document.getElementById('id' + x).title = x;
}
```

Doing it in a `mouseover` handler won't actually break anything, but it means you've registered an event handler that will be invoked (and update the DOM) over and over every time you move from one cell to another.

Comment: You amaze me with simplicity +1

Comment: Event data should go first :)

Comment: thanks..it took you one second to resolve a problem that I struggled for more than an hours.Thanks once again...

Comment: @learner What you are doing doesn't make much sense. I think it can done differently, in a better way if you can give us little more details. (edit: Look at the later part of this post)

Comment: learner : read about closures. Javascript is a very different world when you understand them.

Comment: @Vega thanks for the comment.  One of the maxims I follow is this - _"Perfection is achieved not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away"_

Answer (score 1):

The function you provide to jquery as event handler keeps a pointer to the outside block in which it was defined and to its (living) variables. That's how closure work.

So when it is executed, x is 15.

I know that most javascript developers don't know how that works, but that's a very interesting thing to know : http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

EDIT : I won't add here the usual fix I intended to add as Alnitak pointed before me the fact that a callback was, in fact, totally useless in that case ;)